# Redefinition Issue using Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, definition, multiple-definition-error

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "proto.h"

int main(void)
{

    return(0);
} // end main
```

**support.c:**

```
#include "proto.h"

\\ only function defintions
```

**proto.h:**

```
#ifndef proto
#define proto
double PI = 3.14159;
int LOOP_LIMIT = 90;

#endif
```

**makefile:**

```
main: main.o  support.o 
    gcc -lm -o main main.o support.o
main.o: main.c proto.h
    gcc -c main.c
support.o: support.c proto.h
    gcc -c support.c
```

Whenever I run the makefile with the files defined as above, I always get a multiple definition error, despite having a conditional compilation.

I am not sure what is happening here and how to resolve the issue.

Error message is:

```
multiple definition of `PI'
multiple definition of `LOOP_LIMIT'
```

Comment: Include the actual error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define variables in a header that gets included from more than one compilation unit. `PI` and `LOOP_LIMIT` end up both in `main.o` and in `support.o`, so you get a linker error. The proper way to do it is declaring them `extern` in the header:

**proto.h**

```
#ifndef proto
#define proto
extern double PI;
extern int LOOP_LIMIT;

#endif
```

And then defining them in one and only one .c file:

**support.c**

```
#include "proto.h"

double PI = 3.14159;
int LOOP_LIMIT = 90;

\\ only function defintions
```

By the way, it looks like these guys might be constants rather than variables, so either declare and define them as `const`, or write them as preprocessor definitions:

```
#define PI 3.14159
#define LOOP_LIMIT 90
```

With those, you also avoid the linking problem.

Comment: Bingo, that seems to do the stuff :)
Just one note, why would #define work? Won't there be an attempt to redefine the same thing, as with multiple definition of variables.

Comment: No. `#define` works almost like a copy/paste operation and is handled by the preprocessor, before the compiler even sees the code. So if you write `double circumference = PI * diameter;`, the compiler would see `double circumference = 3.14159 * diameter;`. The actual symbol `PI` does not end up in the compiled object files at all.